# I need validate array codeigniter 4 form

Tags: php, arrays, model, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-form-validation

I have an array of usernames and I need to validate field by field whether it was correctly filled out. I am submitting the form via ajax.

In Ajax I use the following syntax:

```
$.each(response.erros_model, function(key, value) {
    $('#erro_'+key).html('<span class=`text-danger`>' + value + '</span>');
    $('[name='+key+']').addClass('is-invalid');
});
```

My form:

```
<input class=`form-control` name=`user[]` type=`text`>
<div id=`error_user[]`></div>

<input class=`form-control` name=`user[]` type=`text`>
<div id=`error_user[]`></div>`

<input class=`form-control` name=`user[]` type=`text`>
<div id=`error_user[]`></div>
```

I need to put the error individually in each <div id=`error_user[]`>

My validation is:

```
$validation->setRules([
    'user.*' => 'required'
]);

<input class=`form-control` name=`user[]` type=`text` value=`Leonardo` >
<div id=`error_user[]`></div>

<input class=`form-control` name=`user[]` type=`text`>
<div id=`error_user[]`>**This field is required**</div>

<input class=`form-control` name=`user[]` type=`text` value=`Paul`>
<div id=`error_user[]`></div>
```